# Responsive Layout with XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Is possible to use a **Grid with responsiveness** on different **resolution** devices?

I'm learning to create interfaces with **XAML** and I've made the following **Login Application**:

```cs
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,20,Auto,Auto,*" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto">

        <Label HeightRequest="100"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Image Source="gs_logo.png"
                           HeightRequest="350"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

        <Label HeightRequest="110"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Grid.Row="2"/>

        <Image Source="icone_user.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="3"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="User email"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           TextColor="Black"
                           Keyboard="Email"
                           WidthRequest="300"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <!-- More Elements -->

    </Grid>
```

Is it possible to apply **responsiveness** on a Grid? Instead of inserting a `HeightRequest="100"`, applying something like 10% of a screen. Or should I stick to **Flex Layout** or another type of Page?

In the way it is, when I tried to run the app on a different mobile resolution, all of my settings are messed up. *(Only works well in the aspect I've made)*

I've also tried to set it like `"0.1*"`,`"10%"` or `"10*"`. But this gives an error while compiling the code.

Comment: `Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,20,Auto,Auto,*"` you should be able to add * behind the 20 like this `Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,20*,Auto,Auto,*"` Hope this is what you need

Comment: This 20 is more for an image at the side of my entry… I’m considering more about the vertical layout